# Running a ASP & VB.NET & Access website on a PHP/MYSQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, ms-access, asp-classic

Is it possible to implement an ASP website written using VB Script on a PHP MYSQL server. Maybe their is a php interpreter that can parse the asp files or something like that?

Comment: what are your exact needs and why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no php interpreter that can parse the asp files.

Answer (score 1):

Those technologies are very different from each other;

- ASP.NET and VB.NET need IIS or another .NET enabled web server;
- ASP classic and VB script do not need .NET and need IIS or another ASP enabled or compatible web server;
- PHP and MySQL can work on many different web servers including IIS;

depending on your needs and what is your existing codebase you can keep running the existing code or decide to migrate, details more what you have or want to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single interpreter which can parse PHP, ASP and ASP.NET code.  However, you can configure multiple interpreters on a single web server.

I don't know about parsing classic ASP, it's been a long time.  You may need to go with the IIS web server on the Windows platform for that.  Mono certainly hasn't given any attention to classic ASP as far as I know (can't blame them), nor has anybody else.

As far as PHP and ASP.NET are concerned, your top two choices are the IIS web server and the Apache web server.

For the former, ASP.NET comes standard if you install the .NET Framework after the web server (or register it with the web server using aspnet_regiis or something of that nature after installing IIS), and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iisfunc.php) can be [installed on it](http://php.iis.net/) as well.

For the latter, you can install Apache on just about any platform (so you're not restricted to Windows) and install/configure [PHP](http://www.php.net/) and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) with it for interpreting PHP and ASP.NET.

As for MySQL, that's also available on a [variety of platforms](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).  It's a separate service apart from the web server, so it isn't dependent on interpreters and such.  Once it's installed/configured/running, you just need a connection string for it and maybe a [driver library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/) if one isn't available by default.  (You'd likely need one for .NET code, but not for PHP code because it's already available.)

Again, for classic ASP and VBScript, you may have very limited options.  Probably just IIS.  But for the others you have more options to create a custom solution for your needs.